# How do I hide a running application from tint2 in fluxbox?

Tags: 12.04, fluxbox, tint2

Here's the situation:

I have Eterm automatically start when Fluxbox starts. Eterm sits on the desktop layer (Layer 12), it has transparency, no window decoration, etc. I have everything set up exactly how I want it except that it shows up on tint2's task bar as a running app.

I know that if I was running Openbox, I could use "skip_taskbar" in rc.xml, however, I prefer Fluxbox and I cannot find any solution. I have used Fluxbox's [Hidden] and [IconHidden] settings, but neither will work with tint2.

Here's the question:

How do I keep Eterm from appearing as a running task on tint2's task bar while running Fluxbox as my WM?

Screenshot of issue:
[image: Screenshot of issue.]

Comment: People may get upset if you post the same question on more than one SE site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740938/how-do-i-hide-a-running-application-from-tint2-in-fluxbox

Comment: I'm sorry. I originally posted on Stack Overflow but figured that this was a more relevant place to post it. I'll take it down from Stack Overflow immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I feel dumb, but I have learned more of Fluxbox's syntax now.

In the manual at:
http://fluxbox.org/help/man-fluxbox-apps.php
it states that [Hidden] etc. need a {bool} value.

The example gven was: [Hidden] {bool}

Knowing what a Boolean value is, yes/no true/false 1/0 etc. I had it set as:

[Hidden] {True}

I did this because in other files like init, everything true is set to "true". However, it should have been set to:

[Hidden] {YES}

Like I said, I feel like a dummy, but I am glad I learned something. I hope that this experience helps someone else stuck in the same way that I was.